# How to remove entire substring from '<' to '>' in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a program that takes an input string. I want to delete anything inside the characters '<' and '>'. For example if the string says

```
"P.S.<!--
BODY
   {
   color:white;
   background-color: transparent;
   font-family:sans-serif;
   }
--> Hello how are you today?"
```

I want the output string to only contain `"P.S. Hello how are you today?"`. Is there a simple way to do this in Java? Thanks

Comment: and the "<" / ">" combination exists there only once or many times?

Comment: I'd recommend aiming for `<!--*-->` not `<*>` so you're actually pulling out comments, not just any tags.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
newstr = str.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

What this means is to find every substring beginning with `<`, then any number of characters that are not `>`, and then the character `>`. Then replace all these substrings with the empty string, `""`.

Reference: [java.lang.String.replaceAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Maybe you meant `<[^>]*>`?  The current regexp will turn `"<foo>bar<baz> <.>"` into `" <.>"`, not `"bar "`.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Already edited, thanks. What happened was that I initially wanted to use a reluctant quantifier, i.e. `/<.*?>/`, but decided against the conceptual complexity of using it. I made an editing error in the process of changing my decision.

Comment: Thanks, this method worked really well. Is there a method like replaceAll for the Spanned class?

Comment: Its like a string but it has extra stuff like text colors and styles http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/text/Spanned.java.htm

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The key thing to notice is that Scanner extends CharSequence. So you build a pattern, get a matcher on that sequence, and then do a replacement. Namely: `String result = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>").matcher(myscannerobject).replaceAll("");`

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to avoid using regular expressions you can use substring:

```
String origText = "P.S.<!--"+
    "BODY"+
       "{"+
       "color:white;"+
       "background-color: transparent;"+
       "font-family:sans-serif;"+
       "}"+
    "--> Hello how are you today?";
String revised = origText.substring(0, origText.indexOf('<')) +
    origText.substring(origText.lastIndexOf('>')+1, origText.length());
```

`[Java String Class Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: This would fail on `String text = "This <!-- comment -->is a<!-- other comment-->test.";`

Comment: Indeed. To fix, just replace `lastIndexOf('>')` with `indexOf('>')`.

Comment: @glowcoder: true, but the OP didn't specify multiple occurrences.

Comment: @Nayuki indexOf will miss the second occurence. You'd have to loop to use substring with such examples.

Comment: @JJ: The context is quite obvious - it's an XML comment. So while the OP didn't say 'I require multiple occurance handling' his example is clearly a standard which does.

Comment: @JJ The looping would be trivialized by using a `StringBuilder` to build the string. :-)