# Java Regex to remove all words after a key till end key

Tags: java, regex, replace

Can anyone out there please help me ,

i have a file containing several important information but also containing irrelevant information inside it as well  . the irrelevant information is mentioned inside a curly

bracket for example :

Function blah blah 1+2 {unwanted information} something+2

what i wish to do is remove the unwanted information, and display the out put like this :

Function blah blah 1+2  something+2

can some 1 please give me the regex code for this ?

I have a partial code for this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class SimpleReader{

    public static void main( String a[] )
    {
        String source = readFile("source.java");

    }


    static String readFile(String fileName) {

        File file = new File(fileName);

        char[] buffer = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file));

            buffer = new char[(int)file.length()];

            int i = 0;
            int c = bufferedReader.read();

            while (c != -1) {
                buffer[i++] = (char)c;
                c = bufferedReader.read();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String(buffer);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show some effort on your own. And posting irrelevant code is not showing effort. Your title says something different than the text. If you want to learn how to improve your question, read [John Skeets: Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [Matt Gemmells: What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

```
newstr = str.replaceAll("{[^}]*}", "");
```

Modified the answer from this question: [How to remove entire substring from '<' to '>' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100474/how-to-remove-entire-substring-from-to-in-java)